Has "shut" ever meant "open"? (Bear with me, please)
I'm an English language/literature student in a non-English speaking country. As a final project for a literary translation course, my class is taking turns to translate some of the fairy tales compiled in Andrew Lang's Fairy Books from English into our native language.
In one of the translations I'm reviewing, a character asks the village king to say the magic code that opens one of the doors in the palace. The king doesn't really want to open the door, as whoever gets past it will get to marry his daughter. Therefore, when asked to do so, I believe the king is playing dumb when he asks 'What are the words? Shall I say something like this: "Shut; shut; shut"?'
The classmate whose translation I'm checking, however, has decided to translate it as "open; open; open". I don't see what interpretation twist might have made her adapt the text so much, but I don't want to correct such a glaring mistake on the off-chance that she did some sort of historical research and found out there was an alternative meaning to the word "shut". The English version of this particular tale was published by Lang in the early 20th century.
I'm very sorry for asking such a stupid question, but I just wish to know if any of you have heard of something like this.
I thank you all very much in advance!

It looks like an unjustifiable translation, an attempt to correct a non-existent error.

Your first inclination seems right, your classmate just didn't get it.

Can't you just ask her where she got that from? Does she have a reference that suggests it's a possible interpretation, or did she make it up herself?

It's quite common to confuse words with opposite meanings because you often learn them as a pair, but may struggle to remember which is which. I definitely agree that asking her would be more sensible than asking here.
